# Question in real analysis and Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So yeah my school makes us take a mini real analysis course for physics and I am really stumped on this one:
I have the following question and would certainly appreciate any help please : we are given a sigma-finite measure space X and we are given a sequence of measurable functions fn which converge almost everywhere to a function f, we are also given a measurable set of finite measure E in X.

1. I am asked to prove that on E we have convergence in measure of the fn sequence. I managed this.
2. Where I really get stuck: I have the following addition to the question: we are given that for each \epsilon > 0 there exists a K>0 such that for all natural n's we have:
        $$\int |(f_n(x))| \chi_{{f_n>=K}} d \mu < \epsilon $$

and we are asked to prove the following:
       $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int |(f_n(x)) - f(x)| d\mu$$

without using dominated or bounded convergence theorem

3. Using what we have done in 1 and 2 we need to prove the dominated convergence theorem in X which is given as sigma finite

Any help would be great
Thanks to all helpers very much

Comment: Have you seen a proof of Egorov's theorem? You might also look up the notion of uniform integrability (which is your first inequality).

Comment: Yes Ian but I cannot relate what is the relation here sir?

Comment: Egorov's theorem will answer #1 (almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure).

Comment: Thanks appreciated but my problem is mainly with 2 and 3 especially 2 could you please assist me in those in a solution please?